# I am having issues with Android Studio 3.6 canary 7 and canary 6

Tags: android, android-studio

I am receiving an error when using setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); in the onCreate. It worked well on the Android Studio 3.6 canary 5 and after updating to canary 6 is giving me this problem also it causing findViewById(R.id.btn_track);
In the XML it is providing error for all the drawable files. Please help me as soon as possible.
I also attached the screenshots.
Thanking you
Manas Malla
Tech Safari (http://yt.vu/+techsafari)

Build: AI-192.5587.17.36.5787298, 201908071941,

AI-192.5587.17.36.5787298, JRE 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b04x64 JetBrains s.r.o, OS Windows 10(amd64) v10.0 , screens 1366x768

AS: 3.6 Canary 6; Kotlin plugin: 1.3.41-release-Studio3.6-1; Android Gradle Plugin: 3.6.0-alpha06; Gradle: 5.5

The same code works on Android studio 3.5 and Android Studio 3.6 canary 5. But leads to errors on Android Studio 3.6 canary 6/7.
Link to screenshots - https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGbGp.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is was bug in Android Studio 3.6 Canary 6-7. They finally fixed it today in canary 8. Update and give it a try.

Comment: Welcome, you can accept my answer to close this if that solved your issue